# Improving SQL query performance, clarification needed

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a database of stocks information and am trying to mine data from it.

First I set the indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS s1 on Income (symbol, period);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS s2 on BalanceSheet (symbol, period);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS s3 on CashFlow (symbol, period);
```

Then I set up a temporary table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS _;
CREATE TABLE _(symbol, period);
INSERT INTO  _(symbol, period) VALUES ('AAPL', 'Annual');
```

Then I do my select:

```
    SELECT 
        a.yearmonth [Date], a.symbol, a.periodtype [Period],

        -- Income and revenues
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN a.statementitem = 'Revenues' THEN a.value END), 0) Revenue,
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN a.statementitem = 'Other Operating Expense/(Income)' THEN a.value END),0) [Other Operating Expense/(Income)],
        -- ...
        -- ...
        -- ...
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN c.statementitem = 'Depreciation & Amortization, Total' THEN c.value END),0) [Depreciation & Amortization, Total],  -- This one comes from CashFlow
        -- ...
        -- ...
        -- ...
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN b.statementitem = 'Cash And Equivalents' THEN b.value END),0) [Cash And Equivalents],
        COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN b.statementitem = 'Total Cash & ST Investments' THEN b.value END),0) [Total Cash & ST Investments],
        -- ...
        -- ...
        -- ...
FROM _ 
INNER JOIN Income a ON a.symbol = _.symbol AND a.periodtype = _.period 
INNER JOIN BalanceSheet b ON b.symbol = _.symbol AND b.periodtype = _.period 
INNER JOIN CashFlow c ON c.symbol=_.symbol AND c.periodtype = _.period 
GROUP BY a.yearmonth, a.symbol, a.periodtype
```

Two things on the above:

1. This query works
2. This query is slow

What can I do to make it faster, please?

Comment: If you want a temporary table, use `create temp table ...`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The index on all the tables should be on `(symbol, period)`.  However, I don't think that will have a large effect.

From what I can tell, there is little you can do.  The data needs to aggregate a lot of data and that is presumably what is taking time.

Comment: Doesn't look like that did it. When I do 1 join i get instant results, 2 take 4 seconds (pretty much instant. 3 joins take in excess of 5-6 minutes

Comment: @JamesRaitsev . . . All the tables should have an index on both columns -- I see you added additional conditions in the joins.

Comment: Right. I do now index on both Symbol/ Period `CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS s1 on Income (symbol, period);`. Will update the question.

Answer (score 1):

All your joins are `INNER` joins but what you are actually doing is a `CROSS` join of the tables: `Income`, `BalanceSheet` and `CashFlow` filtered for the rows where `symbol = 'AAPL' and periodtype = 'Annual'`.
I don't see the need of the temp table.
A `cross` join of 3 tables is always expensive and indexes could help.
What you could do is make the result of the `cross` joins lighter is drop the temp table and filter before the joins:

```
...............................
FROM (SELECT * FROM Income WHERE symbol = 'AAPL' AND periodtype = 'Annual') a 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM BalanceSheet WHERE symbol = 'AAPL' AND periodtype = 'Annual') b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM CashFlow WHERE symbol = 'AAPL' AND periodtype = 'Annual') c
GROUP BY a.yearmonth, a.symbol, a.periodtype
```